# Printing double without numbers after dot

Tags: c++, double, printf

```
long double ans = fact(n);
fprintf(out,"%lg",ans);
```

What is the best (and shortest variant) to print long double without numbers after dot?
I have no idea. Formatting flag %lg is cant be used in this task, I should print full number.

//Sorry for my bad english, I hope you understand the main idea..

Comment: use fprintf(out,"%n.0lg",ans); n could be any number.

Answer (score 0):

`printf ("%.0lg", var)` is used to print the `long double` variable `var` without digits after the decimal point.

Comment: This will round-off the number. For example, `5.85` will become `6` and `5.35` will become `5`. Not sure if that's what OP wants as opposed to `5` on both occasion.

Comment: @KingsIndian: If you wanted truncation, you could always just subtract 0.5 first.

Answer (score 0):

How about printing it as int (or long) if you don't want the fraction part? :

```
fprintf(out,"%d",(int)ans);
```